# Transit via UK with a valid IM1 visa

Tags: uk, air-travel, transit, india

Background: My family has extended visitor record and study permit (but not the VISA stamped on their passport)

Also I have recently got my approved PR approved and have onetime IM-1 VISA stamped on their passports.

Question: Can I travel to India via UK? Will this one time visa be considered valid Canadian visa (required to transit via UK)

Comment: Did they draw a line across the visa? Have you got your PR card yet?

Comment: No there is no line drawn across my Visa, I havent completed my landing yet